# The eigenvectors of DFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing

As we know discrete  Fourier transform, DFT enjoys four eigenvalues $\{\pm1,\pm i\}$ whose multiplicities depend on the order. So, one may find many eigenvectors corresponded to the eigenvalues.

In some papers in which there is a discussion on eigenvectors of discrete  Fourier transform DFT, I face the following sentence:  **we are usually interested in the real-valued,
orthogonal, symmetric eigenvectors of the DFT matrix**. What could be the reason for this point of view?

Comment: What do you mean by “orthogonal” or “symmetric” here?

Comment: Let us denote  $J$ by  the antidiagonal matrix. We say an $n$-tuple vector $v$ is symmetric if $Jv=v$.

Comment: Since we are taking about vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$, when we say that,  two vectors are orthogonal, it   means the inner product is zero.